# Volley image cache

Tags: android, caching, imageview, android-volley

I don't understand how can I get a cached image from a NetworkImageView provided by Volley library, I need to use this image offline, I read that volley implement a disk cache but I don't fin'd any document of how can use it.
Where can I find some info or how can I use this cache?